# Why don't the spectres in HDM attack Mary Malone?

Tags: his-dark-materials

In Amber Spyglass it is mentioned that the spectres dont attack Mary. Do we ever learn why this is?

Comment: The angels or the dust protects her.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Mary is communicating with the Angels using her modified equipment she is told:

> Take provisions for a long journey. You will be protected. The
>   Spectres will not touch you.

As far as I can recall we are not told any more than this.

Comment: I've always assumed the angels protect her. We see angles fight spectres in the Amber Spyglass so evidently they can and will.

Comment: @Sam - I agree, that seems the most likely reason.